# On a Canadian work permit, which number is the work permit number?

Tags: working-visas, canada, documentation

A work permit issued by Canada has some numbers that are not labelled explicitly.

- an 11-digit number (like BB123 456 789) in red ink at the top right, in a rounded box
- a 10 digit number (like U123456789) in black ink below the rounded box

There are also these labelled numbers:

- OFF. FILE NO (like W123456789)
- CLIENT ID. (like 1234 - 5678)

Which of these numbers is the Work Permit number? And what are the other unlabelled numbers called?

[image]

Comment: Do you have an update on this? What number did you end up using?

Comment: No update. I used the one in black ink.

Comment: If a number has 9 numerical digits, and the first digit is "9", it's likely your temporary Social Insurance Number.

Comment: Use the number in black ink that starts with 1 letter and then has 9 digits

Answer (score 2):

It's the one that says **UCI** or **Unique Client Identifier** which according to your question is the **Client ID**. This is the number that is used everywhere (may it be for extending the work permit or applying for permanent residence).

This number remains the same for your period of stay in Canada. If is of the format:

> four numbers, a hyphen and four more numbers (Example: 0000-0000) or
>
> two numbers, a hyphen, four numbers, a hyphen and four more numbers
> (Example: 00-0000-0000)

You can find more info about UCI [here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=013&top=4) and [here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=772&top=4).

I am guessing the other numbers are used by CIC internally and I have never needed these numbers for anything in that matter.

Also, this was the message written on one of the letter I received from CIC which was regarding my work permit.

[image]

If something provides personal information to my file, it should be the number that CIC would ask in this case.

Comment: I doubt this, because on some forms such as [IMM5708E](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/pdf/kits/forms/imm5708E.pdf) they ask for both UCI and a 'Document Number' - "If applicable, provide the document number of the most recent Visitor Record, Study Permit, Work Permit or Temporary Resident Permit issued to you"

Comment: @Liam UCI is not always known as mentioned [here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=013&top=4) if you're applying for the first time. As you said `most recent Visitor Record, Study Permit, Work Permit or Temporary Resident Permit` it could mean any type of document, **not just work permits**. In case of work permits, it is always the UCI. You could have a study permit but be applying for a work permit. In that case, the UCI would be the one mentioned on your study permit.

Comment: @Liam UCI is not a compulsory field if you noticed in the form you linked.